# How can I use an 'update' function to 'open' and update if the object is not yet open?

Tags: python

My example is a progress bar

In its simplest form a progress bar is

```
bar = ProgressBar.Open()
for item in list:
    bar.Update(count, len(list))
```

I would instead like my calling code to be

```
for item in list:
    bar.Update(count, len(list))
```

I want my `Update()` function to `Open()` a bar for the caller if one is not open.  The caller doesn't need any other access to the bar than to update it so there's no value in having the meter` handle.

How can I retain state to tell if the Update had been previously called?

### I could create a global variable and keep track that way, but I have a gut sense there's a Pythonista way of doing it.

Trying again, but in a way that has no application to stumble on.

The base question is:
I have a function that will be called multiple times.
I want to do something different the first time it is called.
How can a function in Python do that?

In C, that of course would be a...
static variable

I'm just now kinda figuring it out as I type, sorry.

========================

I'm sure all these edits are not how stackoverflow is supposed to work. I'm sorry for not getting it right yet, but am very appreciative of the replies.

Despite it sounding like I'm breaking all the rules of good practices, it's when looked at from the CALLER'S point of view that I had hoped to make an impact.

What if the only thing you needed to do to add a progress meter, even for debugging, to your program was make a call to a progress meter update in the location you want to show progress?

That's the underlying motivation.  Slide in 1-line, get something cool for the trouble.

This progress meter was added to my otherwise boring file de-duplicator by adding just the single call:

```
msg = f'Deduplicating {idx} of {total_files} files\n' f'{dup_count} Dupes found\n' f'{small_count} Too small'
not_cancelled = sGUI.ProgressBar('De-dupe', msg, idx, total_files)
```

[image: Progress Bar Screen Shot]

Comment: use own varialble like `opened = True` to control it

Comment: What would `bar` be if you didn't open the progress bar?

Comment: what is `ProgressBar` ? is it some GUI element ? what GUI ?

Comment: BTW: you can set at start `bar = None` and later check if it is still `None`. If it is `None` then you need `bar = ProgressBar.Open()`

Comment: `if not self.opened: self.Open()`?

Comment: I am both the caller and callee, and yes a 'Progress Bar' is the kind of thing I'm working on.
I agree my for loop could be written much better, as shown.  I broke it out and was overly wordly on purpose. I wanted the calls to Open and Update be obvious.  Trying to focus everyone on that part of my problem, not the loop itself.

Comment: Maybe I should have made it even more abstract?  

I want a function to do one thing the first time I call it and something different the second time I call it.  How about that as the question?

Comment: if `ProgressBar` is your class then you should rebuild it so you can create it at start as `bar = ProgressBar()` without opening, and it should remember its state inside as `self.opened = False`. And inside `Update()` it should check `self.opened` and open it.

Comment: @MikeyB so, add an internal flag `self.opened` to your `Bar` class, then, use that check `if self.opened:` in `def Update(self):`

Comment: I do understand the normal model of open, then update.  Implementing something that way is straightforward.

Yes, I'm talking about a GUI element

I'm working on a 'simpleGUI' with the goal of having the absolute least number of calls required from the user of the package.

I don't need to run multiple progress bars at one time either. I'm not going to worry about multi-threaded apps wanting many progress meters.

1 less call seemed like a pretty good thing.  
You could also think of it like a write_file function that opens and writes the data.
write_file(';filename", data)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using global variables, you can use decorator. Here's a simple example:

```
def open():
    print 'open'


def update():
    print 'update'


def call_once(func1, *args1, **kwargs1):
    def decorator(func2):
        called = [False]

        def wrapper(*args2 ,**kwargs2):
            if not called[0]:
                func1(*args1, **kwargs1)
                called[0] = True
            return func2(*args2, **kwargs2)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@call_once(open)
def my_update():
    update()


for i in xrange(5):
    my_update()
```

which give the result:

```
open
update
update
update
update
update
```

For more information about decorator, please visit: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Comment: AH!  THIS is what I was hoping for!  Thank you very much.  I have a lot yet to learn about Python, that's for sure.  There's a LOT of depth to Python that is easy to overlook on the first pass.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want, you can use a class:

```
class ProgressBar:
    def __init__(self):
        self._opened = False
    def Open(self):
        print("Open")
    def Update(self):
        if self._opened:
            print("Update!")
        else:
            self.Open()
            print("set flag")
            self._opened = True
         print("Update")
```

In action:

```
In [32]: bar = ProgressBar()

In [33]: bar.Update()
Open
set flag
Update

In [34]: bar.Update()

Update!
```

Note: I copied your casing so as to make it more clear to you, however, the official Python style would be like this:

```
class ProgressBar:
    def __init__(self):
        self._opened = False
    def open(self):
        pass # open stuff
    def update(self):
        if self._opened:
            pass # update stuff
        else:
            self.open()
            self._opened = True
```

Using `snake_case` for everything except the `ClassName`.

Comment: @MikeyB this is what I meant

Comment: Ah, right, yes.  But... this solution uses two calls.  The instantiation of the class is much like an "open" call.

I'm looking for the true, 1-call solution, from the point of view of the caller.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution using 'globals'. I thought that a nested function was the way to do it... then I mixed the two.

By 'globals' I meant variables declared outside the scope of a function.  I want to be able to import my module without the import creating anything.

Here's the code that shows how to do this with globals

```
def my_update(amount):
    global flag
    if 'flag' in globals():
        print('I have been here')
    else:
        print('I have not been here')
    flag = True

    return


for i in range(10):
    print(f'Calling number {i}')
    result = my_update(1)
```

It does the job for the goals I had set out, but I'm SURE there are better, safer ways that are more elegant as well.

Comment: Oh crap, you're right... I don't need that nested function. The global on it's own works.

Comment: Yeah, but don't do that. Use a class to encapsulate state. That's what OOP is for.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that with a snippet of code?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on a Python forum and got back the best answer so far using a function attribute.  It's brilliant and it works.

Here is code that demonstrates this construct... it should go in everyone's 'Favorite Python Constructs' notebook in my opinion.

```
def func():
    if not hasattr(func, 'static_variable'):
        func.static_variable = 0

    func.static_variable += 1
    return func.static_variable


def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print('func = {}'.format(func()))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is

```
func = 1
func = 2
func = 3
func = 4
func = 5
func = 6
func = 7
func = 8
func = 9
func = 10
```